# Can you use "elated" to describe something like "service"?

Tags: word-usage

Can you use the word “elated” as an adjective to describe something that isn’t attributable to a person or living thing?

Can “customer service” be elated?

I’m editing an advertisement that talks about employees delivering “elated” service, and it doesn’t sound right to me. Synonyms include happy, elevated, excited — almost all words that you would attach to a person or living being, but not to a material object.

Comment: Seems like an odd usage. Are you sure they didn't mean elevated? Elated seems over the top — but this is advertising. I'm hesitant to say that advertising language bordering on puffery is acceptable, but we all know it's common enough.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of "elevated" as in "an elevated level of service."

Comment: It is wrong. It would mean that the service is elated. Elation is an emotion. Abstract objects (e.g. "service") do not have emotions.

Comment: The customer may be elated with the service, but the service is still not "elated".

Comment: Odd turns of phrase sometimes work, especially in advertising. It depends on how you craft the message.